# Issues in expanding expressions with formal sums

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, summation, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have a very long expression involving formal sums to infinity, unfixed functions and several variables.

In this very long expression, I need a typical term, like

$\frac{6 A \sigma  \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 A (n+1)^2 e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } (m+1) (m+2) w^m \sigma ^n a(n+1,m+2)\right)}{w^3}+(n+1) e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \left(\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } m (m+1) (m+2) w^{m-1} \sigma ^n a(n+1,m+2)\right)\right)}{w^3}$,

to be given like,

$\frac{6 A \sigma  \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (n+1) e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } m (m+1) (m+2) w^{m-1} \sigma ^n a(n+1,m+2)}{w^3}+\frac{2 A \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (n+1)^2 e^{-\frac{A (n+1)}{w^2}} \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } (m+1) (m+2) w^m \sigma ^n a(n+1,m+2)}{w^6}$,

i.e to be expanded.

I need to do this for quite a lot of terms, and Mathematica's Expand or ExpandAll doesn't work.

Here's the code:

What I want is,

```
(6/w^3)*A*\[Sigma]*
  Sum[((1 + n)*
      Sum[m*(1 + m)*(2 + m)*w^(-1 + m)*\[Sigma]^n*
        a[1 + n, 2 + m], {m, 0, Infinity}])/E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2), {n, 
    0, Infinity}] + 
   (2/w^6)*A*
  Sum[((1 + n)^2*
      Sum[(1 + m)*(2 + m)*w^m*\[Sigma]^n*a[1 + n, 2 + m], {m, 0, 
        Infinity}])/E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2), {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

What I have is,

```
(6*A*\[Sigma]*
   Sum[((1 + n)*
        Sum[m*(1 + m)*(2 + m)*w^(-1 + m)*\[Sigma]^n*
          a[1 + n, 2 + m], {m, 0, Infinity}])/E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2) + 
          (2*A*(1 + n)^2*
        Sum[(1 + m)*(2 + m)*w^m*\[Sigma]^n*a[1 + n, 2 + m], {m, 0, 
          Infinity}])/(E^((A*(1 + n))/w^2)*w^3), {n, 0, Infinity}])/
 w^3
```

Comment: Can you put the code you used in the question.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code (**InputForm**) for these expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit

Comment: What is your goal? What kind of final result do you want to get?